# Formula for joint density with i.i.d Uniform random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. $U(0,\theta )$-distributed random variables. Show that $\frac{X_{(1)}}{X_{(n)}}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are independent random variables.

I have been given a solution for this so I don't need help solving it. But the solution starts with:

> $f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x,y)$ = $\frac{d^2}{dxdy}$$(F(y)-F(x))^n$

I'm a bit confused by this because I thought that that the joint density was defined by:

$f_{X_{1},X_{n}}(x,y)$ = $\frac{d^2}{dxdy}$$F_{X_{n},X_{n}}(x,y)$=$\frac{d^2}{dxdy}$$(F(y)F(x))$

Is this a different formula because it is a Uniform distribution? That is the only reason I can come up with that could explain why it is a different formula.

Comment: Note that $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are **order statistics**, as opposed to $X_1$ and $X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with 
$$
\eqalign{
\Bbb P[X_{(1)}>x,X_{(n)}\le y]
&=\Bbb P[x<X_i\le y,\forall i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}]\cr
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\Bbb P[x<X_i\le y]\cr
&=[F(y)-F(x)]^n=(y-x)^n,\cr
}
$$
for $0\le x\le y\le 1$. The joint density on $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is then given by
$$
-{\partial^2\over\partial x\partial y}(y-x)^n=n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2},
$$
for $0\le x\le y\le 1$.